# How to save a listview using shared preference

Tags: java, sharedpreferences

I've made a simple shopping list app where the user can add items to the listview. My problem is when I leave the app the items do not save. I think I need to use a shared preference but haven't had much look implementing it (I'm fairly new to coding) If anyone knows how to implement the shared preference so my items will save it would be much appreciated.

My code:

```
public class CreateAList extends AppCompatActivity {
    //ArrayList for data
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView list_view;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_alist);
        //find view by id
        list_view = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(CreateAList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        list_view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

                //Inflating is the process of adding a view(.xml) to activity on runtime
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(CreateAList.this,view);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                                case R.id.item_update:
                                    //function for update
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAList.this);
                                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(CreateAList.this).inflate(R.layout.item_dialog,null,false);
                                    builder.setTitle("Update Item");
                                    final EditText editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editItem);
                                    editText.setText(list.get(i));


                                    //set custom view to dialog
                                    builder.setView(v);

                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            if (!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                                list.set(i, editText.getText().toString().trim());
                                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                Toast.makeText(CreateAList.this, "Item Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }else{
                                                editText.setError("add item here!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    builder.show();

                                    break;

                                case R.id.item_delete:
                                    //function for delete
                                    Toast.makeText(CreateAList.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   list.remove(i);
                                   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                   break;

                            }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
                    popupMenu.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add_item:

                //function to add

                addItem();

                break;

        }

        return true;
    }
//method for adding item
    private void addItem() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAList.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add new Item");

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(CreateAList.this).inflate(R.layout.item_dialog,null,false);

        builder.setView(v);
        final EditText editItem = v.findViewById(R.id.editItem);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (!editItem.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    list.add(editItem.getText().toString().trim());
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    editItem.setError("Add Item Here!");
                }

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to go through a tutorial for shared preference. This way you will learn more. Also look for SQLite database that Android provides to store data. I think that will be much better approach if you have simple objects in your list view.

Here is a good tutorial : https://medium.com/@evancheese1/shared-preferences-saving-arraylists-and-more-with-json-and-gson-java-5d899c8b0235

Answer (score 0):

void putSharedPreferencesStringSet(String key, Set value)

```
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME", 0).edit();
    edit.putStringSet(key, value);
    edit.apply();
}

void putSharedPreferencesStringSet(String key, String value)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editoredit = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME", 0).edit();
    edit.putString(key, value);
    edit.apply();
}

String getSharedPreferencesString(String key)
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = AppConstants.appContext.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
    return prefs.getString(key, 0);
}

void removeSharedPreferencesString(String key)
{
    SharedPreferences edit = AppConstants.appContext.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
    edit.remove(key);
    edit.apply();

}
```

//the above functions are about add , get and remove sharedPrefrences

Another way if you need to use database when ever you add items in to your cart